# Home.html.twig.twig - С какой целью? Symfony2

Tags: twig, php, symfony2

Доброе время суток
Во время генерации нового бандла получил ошибку:

> [Twig_Error_Loader] Unable to find
> template "bundle/home.html.twig.twig".

На генерацию бандла сильно не повлияло, но стало как-то странно. Пошел искать по проекту строку `home.html.twig.twig`, нашел(очень неожиданно) в файлах генерации бандла. Вопрос: зачем так сделали? Посмотрел файл дальше - там таких `html.twig.twig` еще полно.

Comment: При генерации бандла чем? Стандартными средствами (консолью) симфони?

Comment: Да, при генерации консолью

Comment: у меня просто при генерации бандла создается только Default:index.html.twig и больше ничего

Answer (score 1):

вряд ли кто-то сделал так специально, больше похоже на ошибки. либо какой-то глюк шаблонизатора, либо просто не верно указаны пути к подключаемым файлам в шаблонах